# monitoring memcached stats with openNMS

Tags: memcached, monitoring, opennms

did anyone tried monitoring memcached statistics with openNMS?
If you did, what did you use?

Answer (score 3):

Since version 1.7.4, there'd a [memcached monitor](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Memcached_Monitor) bundled with [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Main_Page).